# Problem when using lessThanOrEqualTo() of Predicate when compare time

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, criteria

Source code

```java
Expression<LocalDateTime> dateTimeFromDatabase = root.get("period").as(LocalDateTime.class);
Expression<LocalTime> timeFromDatabase = dateTimeFromDatabase.as(LocalTime.class);
LocalTime periodToRequest = FormatUtils.getLocalDateTime(request.getPeriodTo(), "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss").toLocalTime().plusMinutes(30);
Predicate predicate = criteriaBuilder.lessThanOrEqualTo(timeFromDatabase, periodToRequest.plusMinutes(30));
```

I have a column in database that datatype is datetime. I using JPA, Specification to get it with Criteria.
In my request, I pass in "period_to" ex: "31-Mar-2023 07:30:00"
I wanna to implement dynamic filter, that compare the only time that I pass in request("07:30:00") with the time that I take from database.
And I meet the error:
`com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The data types time and datetime are incompatible in the less than or equal to operator.`

- The datatime in database is `2023-03-31 08:00:00.000`.
- The period_to that I pass in is `31-Mar-2023 07:30:00`.
- I wanna compare `07:30:00` with `08:00:00`.

I need your help, thank you!

Comment: did you read this part of the error: The data types time and datetime are incompatible in the less than or equal to operator.?

Comment: yes, I'm searching for it but don't get any way to fix it.

Comment: the first i get Expression<LocalDateTime> and convert it into Expression<LocalTime>. After that, I try to compare with the LocalTime that I pass in but the error happen to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of 2 known solution: In `spring.data.url`, concate to end of string

```
sendTimeAsDateTime=false
```

for example, original

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://DESKTOP-EQBT80R\\MSSQLSERVER:1433;database=FooSample;trustServerCertificate=true;
```

change to

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://DESKTOP-EQBT80R\\MSSQLSERVER:1433;database=FooSample;trustServerCertificate=true;sendTimeAsDateTime=false;
```

Let's share with your result.

Comment: Thank you, it's work, but it need to change in a application.properties file. 
And I avoid to edit that file. Is there have any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```java
LocalTime periodToRequest = FormatUtils.getLocalDateTime(request.getPeriodTo(), "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss").toLocalTime().plusMinutes(30);
```

to

```java
LocalDateTime periodToRequest = FormatUtils.getLocalDateTime(request.getPeriodTo(), "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss").plusMinutes(30L);
```

Reference document: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#plusMinutes-long-

Comment: I am not sure it works, because I don't setup development environment now, it is cumbersome.